How to monitor multiple kubernetes clusters using grafana and prometheus from a separate cluster?
I have three kubernetes clusters. (monitoring, one, two). monitoring cluster is dedicated for monitoring tools. So on monitoring cluster, I will install prometheus and grafana. On other cluster should not install complete prometheus again. But just can install node exporter and kube state metrics on other clusters and fetch data from them.
When I checked few blogs, got below steps.
# prometheus-values.yaml
server:
  global:
    scrape_interval: 15s
  persistentVolume:
    enabled: true
    size: 8Gi
  additionalScrapeConfigs:
    - job_name: 'cluster-one-node-exporter'
      static_configs:
        - targets: ['<cluster-one-ip>:30091']
    - job_name: 'cluster-one-kube-state-metrics'
      static_configs:
        - targets: ['<cluster-one-ip>:30092']
    - job_name: 'cluster-two-node-exporter'
      static_configs:
        - targets: ['<cluster-two-ip>:30091']
    - job_name: 'cluster-two-kube-state-metrics'
      static_configs:
        - targets: ['<cluster-two-ip>:30092']

And grafana.yml.
# grafana-values.yaml
persistence:
  enabled: true
  size: 5Gi

datasources:
  datasources.yaml:
    apiVersion: 1
    datasources:
    - name: Prometheus-Monitoring
      type: prometheus
      url: http://prometheus-server.monitoring.svc.cluster.local
      access: proxy
      isDefault: true
    - name: Prometheus-ClusterOne
      type: prometheus
      url: http://prometheus-server.monitoring.svc.cluster.local
      access: proxy
    - name: Prometheus-ClusterTwo
      type: prometheus
      url: http://prometheus-server.monitoring.svc.cluster.local
      access: proxy

dashboards:
  default:
    cluster-metrics:
      gnetId: 315
      revision: 3
      datasource: Prometheus-Monitoring

but not showing the data of  kubernetes cluster. Please suggest any alternative steps.

Install node exporter on your 2 Kubernetes clusters helm install node-exporter prometheus-community/prometheus-node-exporter.  Expose node exporter using an Ingress or NodePort. Without these services you cannot access your node exporter. What errors do you have?

I installed node exporter and configured that using these steps https://github.com/uday1kiran/MyBlog/blob/elasticsearch/kubernetes/monitoring/grafana_and_prometheus_mulicluster/one_grafana_one_prometheus_multiple_node_exporters_and_kube_state_metrics.md . But in the drop down, it is not showing option to choose clusters in any dashboard: 6417 13105
9100

You need to add access point like load balancer or NodePORT of the Prometheus-ClusterOne & Two clusters. check connectivity between the Monitoring and Prometheus servers.
